# Je suis content pour toi ou Je me réjouis pour toi

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Ou mieux encore:

Je me réjouis avec toi de cet heureux événement.

Contexte:

Interlocuteur: J’ai gagné un bon montant à la loterie.

Comment: L'emploi de ces différentes phrases dépendant du contexte, il faut donc "include more details and clarify the problem".

Comment: J'suis content pour toi, j'espère que tu vas partager.

Comment: Ce type de question sort du cadre de FSE car les réponses seraient forcément subjectives. Toutes les formules que tu proposes sont valables. Les deux premières différent sur le plan du registre, la troisième n'est pas mieux ou moins bien, comment peut-on savoir si tu tutoies ou vouvoies cet interlocuteur ? Je te conseille d'utilise le [chat], qui n'est pas aussi strictement formaté Q&R, pour ce type d'interrogation.

Comment: *d'utilise**r***

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Un ngram montre que « content pour toi » et « réjouis pour toi » sont utilisés dans les livres avec une fréquence accrue depuis le début du siècle, mais la préposition « pour » ne figure ni dans le TLFi ni dans le Larousse en tant que préposition naturelle pour ce verbe et cet adjectif.

[image]

[se réjouir, TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9jouir), [content, TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/content)

[se réjouir, Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/r%C3%A9jouir/67812) [content, Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/content/18571)

Si on examine l'entrée « pour » dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pour) on s'aperçoit qu'il n'y a qu'une acception qui serait compatible avec la relation entre la satisfaction éprouvée et l'individu qui est la cause des circonstances dont résulte cette satisfaction (TLFi : 2. [Le compl. désigne une chose] À propos de; au sujet de.) ; cependant, le complément doit être une chose, et la satisfaction n'est pas au sujet de l'individu (ce qui ne semble pas avoir de sens) mais au sujet des circonstances qui sont favorables à cette personne. En d'autres termes, il n'est pas logique de mettre en relation directe la satisfaction et l'individu. La préposition que l'on trouve dans les deux cas dans les dictionnaires est « de » (se réjouir de, content de), et bien sûr, le complément ne peut plus avoir pour référent l'individu. Il faut penser différemment.

- Je suis content de ce qui vous arrive
- Je me réjouis de ce qui vous arrive

(de ce qui vous arrive/de cet évènement/de votre fortune à la loterie/…)

Donc,  recourir à l'usage  de la préposition « pour » (facile parce que  ces formes sont souvent utilisées) et faire une connection directe entre satisfation et individu résulte en une énonciation qui dénature la réalité, à moins bien sûr, de fournir à cet usage une signification idiomatique (ce qui ne semble pas avoir été fait), un sens qui ne reflète pas celui que seuls les mots permettent.

Bien que d'apparence anodine  et malgré leur usage courant dans la langue familière,  ces formes sont indésirables ; l'insinuation de doute qui est manifestée dans la question  à leur propos, et la proposition d'une forme alternative maintenant reconnue comme appropriée et correspondant à la présente analyse¹,  à mon avis,  tend  à confirmer cela.

¹<sub>On ne peut parler de confirmation, bien sûr, que si cette proposition provient d'une expérience générale non rationalisée de la langue et non d'une analyse similaire à la mienne.</sub>